# how to prevent confirm alert In Spring MVC on F5

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, submit, page-refresh

In Spring I usually did a redirect-after-submit(get method `mapping`) to prevent the user of submitting a form ,
but when i pressing `F5` it will go to get method `mapping` again and display me this kind of confirm message. how could i prevent this message every time on `F5`.

[image]

Here is the code for controller -

```
 ScheduleDetail objScheduleDetail = new ScheduleDetail();       
 HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
 String condition = "";
 try{
      int careProfessionalIDF = (Integer) session.getAttribute("careProfessionalIDF");
      condition = "CareProfessionalIDF = "+careProfessionalIDF;
      objScheduleDetail.setCareProfessionalIDF(careProfessionalIDF);

    }catch (Exception e) {
      int careProviderIDF = (Integer) session.getAttribute("careProviderIDF");
      condition = "CareProviderIDF = "+careProviderIDF;
      objScheduleDetail.setCareProviderIDF(careProviderIDF);
    }

    List<ScheduleDetail> ScheduleDetailList = objScheduleDetailManager.getAllScheduleDetail(condition+" ORDER BY ScheduleDetailIDP DESC");
    model.addObject("List_of_ScheduleDetail",ScheduleDetailList);
    model.addAttribute("ScheduleDetail", objScheduleDetail);
    return "hospital/scheduleDetail";//jsp page
```

**edited code**

```
 @RequestMapping("/editAddressType.html")
    public String editAddressType(ModelMap model,HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        int addressTypeIDP = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("AddressTypeIDP"));

        AddressType objAddressType = new AddressType();
        objAddressType = objAddressTypeManager.getByID(addressTypeIDP); 

        model.addAttribute("AddressType", objAddressType);

        return "jsp/addressType"; 

it open addressType.jsp with data tht we bind with `model.addAttribute`. now if i press F5 it show alert message as above image.

**get method**

    @RequestMapping(value="/getAddressType.html", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAddressType(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) throws RemoteException
    {
        AddressType objAddressType = new AddressType();
        model.addAttribute("AddressType", objAddressType);

        return "hospital/addressType";
    }
```

Comment: The image is not visible. Can you explain what kind of confirm message are you getting??

Comment: `To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier`

Comment: If you are redirecting to another get request this should not happen. It will only happen if you are returning a JSP after the post request.

Comment: i use `redirect:getScheduleDetail.html` for redirect and this mapping have [this code](http://pastebin.com/Pz6wbppS)  .

Comment: I am not able to access the link of code you have provided from my office. Can you edit the question and display the code of controller?

Comment: you just need to return string value like `return "redirect:mapped-url-for-get-method"`. this is enough to get rid of message dialog you are getting.

Comment: please find edited question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you implement the POST - REDIRECT - GET pattern correctly, you will not see the warning from the browser that you mentioned. The warning is shown when the Page being viewed is in response to a POST request. The traditional pattern, FORM - POST - SUCCESS page.

The code you provided in the question is not enough to reach the root cause of the problem. I'm listing key points of the implementation here, please compare with your code and you'll understand what the mistake is.

1. To show the user the form, where they are supposed to enter data for submission. (Just the starting point, could be any page in your application.)

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/checkout/{cartId}.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView showCheckoutForm(...) {
        ......
        return new ModelAndView("/WEB-INF/jsp/form.jsp")
   }
   ```
2. The form POSTs to a handler method, which issues a redirect to the user, pointing to a URL that will show the details of the resource created as a result of the POST.

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/checkout/{cartId}.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public View submitCheckoutForm(....) {
        return new RedirectView("/checkout/confirmation/" + cartId + ".htm");
   }
   ```
3. The details of the created resource will be shown by a handler method like the following. Note that at this point, if your implementation worked properly, the URL in the user's browser will change to the path redirected by the POST handler. And a fresh GET request will be issued to the server.

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/checkout/confirmation/{cartId}.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView showCheckoutConfirmation(....) {
         return new ModelAndView("viewThatShowsCheckoutConfirmation");
   }
   ```

If your implementation is similar, the confirmation page is a result of a GET request, so browsers won't issue a warning for re-POSTing data if you refresh the page.

My suspicion is that your POST handler is not issuing a redirect to the user, it is instead rendering the confirmation page itself.

Hope this helps. Please let me know if this does not solve your problem.

Comment: your controller is returning a jsp view, so just like I mentioned in my answer, your controller is showing apage in response to a post request,  instead of issuing a client redirect.  is my answer not clear enough? let me know if you need more details.

Comment: so what changes required to my `edited code` for prevent confirm alert..?

Comment: @VijayRamani, it would be better if you compare your implementation with the pattern I presented, it will help you understand how to correctly implement the POST-REDIRECT-GET pattern. None the less, if you want me to pinpoint where the problem is, you'll have to show me the method which is supposed to handle the GET request also, the controller you've shown now, seems to be used for handling the POST request. As you can see, there is already a problem with your POST handler, it is serving a jsp, instead of issuing a client side redirect to the URL that is supposed to serve the GET request.

Comment: `@Akshay Singhal` thanks for your reply. but what i want to know is if i redirect to get method from `@RequestMapping("/editAddressType.html")` will i get all value that i have set in `AddressType` bean. and find get method for this controller at edited question.

Comment: @VijayRamani, the redirected GET request is an independent request, its like the user typed the url into the browser address bar and hit enter. Which means any bean you set into the model in the post handler will NOT be available to the GET method. By definition a GET method is meant to get a resource, identified by the url or optional url params. So, there needs to be an id of some sort in your GET url. In your handler, use this id to fetch the required details from the backend and send it to the jsp.

Comment: In the example I provided, /checkout/confirmation/{cartId}.htm is the get request, I use the cartId from the url to fetch details from the database and send it to the jsp.

Comment: @VijayRamani If you need the `AddressType` to be available after a redirect use [RedirectAttributes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html) which stores flash attributes.

Comment: Interesting, I received a downvote on my answer. It would have been nice if the user had left a note explaining what was lacking in my response.